# How to take screenshot of any URL using python version 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, power-automate

I need to take screenshot of a power BI report using **python-2.x**, I want to pass Power BI URL. That URL will have flow like this -> **email -> submit, then password -> SignIn then stay SignIn -> yes**, I have tried below code. **I have to run this script in power automate and power automate supports only python2 as of now.**

```
import datetime
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

def login_powerbi(username, password):
    # Set up the ChromeDriver path in the PATH environment variable
    chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Screenshot/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

    # Set up the webdriver
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

    try:
        # Open the Power BI report URL (login page)
        driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/")

        # Wait for the login page to load
        time.sleep(5)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

        email_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
        actionChains.click(email_field).send_keys(username).perform()
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id=submitBtn]").click()

        time.sleep(5)
        # Wait for the password field to load and then enter the password
        password_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[type=password]")))
        actionChains.click(password_field).send_keys(password).perform()

        # Submit the password form
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id=idSIButton9]").click()

        # Wait for the "Stay signed in?" prompt to load and then click "Yes"
        time.sleep(3)
        stay_signed_in_prompt = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "idSIButton9")))  # idSIButton9
        stay_signed_in_prompt.click()

        # Wait for the Power BI report to load after authentication
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)

        # Add a delay before taking the screenshot to ensure the report is fully loaded
        time.sleep(10)

        # Take the screenshot
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        file_name = 'powerBI_{}.png'.format(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))
        output_path = "C:/Users/Desktop/Screenshot/output/"

        screenshot_output_file = os.path.join(output_path, file_name)
        screenshot_BI = driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_output_file)
        print(screenshot_BI)
        print("Screenshot saved as {}".format(screenshot_output_file))

    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        # Re-locate the element and retry the action
        print("Stale element reference, retrying...")
        login_powerbi(username, password)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error during login and screenshot capture: {}".format(e))

    finally:
        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace 'your_username' and 'your_password' with your actual Power BI login credentials
    login_powerbi("your@mail.com", "password")
```

**The above script is failing from this line** -> actionChains.click(password_field).send_keys(password).perform(), getting this error -> Message: stale element reference: stale element not found

Comment: Question: why are you still using Python 2.7? Does this _have_ to use that now long-dead version of Python, or can it be normal Python 3, too?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I have to run the script in power automate, that supports python2 only

Comment: In that case, remember to tag your post with the technologies involved ;) That said though, do you have to use power automate at all or do you just need any task runner (i.e. Windows task scheduler), mostly because if a product forces you to still be on 2.7, it might be time to replace the use of that product with something else.

Comment: I have to use power automate only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was generating -> StaleElementReferenceException

```
actionChains.click(password_field).send_keys(password).perform()
```

for solving this send keys in field locator itself

```
password_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[type=password]"))).send_keys(password)
```